# HoldForm -> InputForm without processing the contents

Tags: output-formatting, hold

I have programmatically generated a large number of simple equations like `1+1/2`. I need them to be 'unprocessed', so they've been run through `HoldForm[]` and appear like

[image: 1+1/2]

The problem is, for the next stage in my work (which will take place outside of *Mathematica*), I really need these to be in `InputForm`, but still unprocessed. In other words, I need `1+1/2`, not 1.5 or the "prettier" form shown above.

Is there any way to transform a `StandardForm` equation inside `HoldForm` into a `InputForm` while still "holding" it unprocessed?

Comment: Could you expand on what you need to do in your next step where you say that you need the expressions to be in InputForm?

Comment: The replacement `HoldForm[x__] :> HoldForm[InputForm[x]]` seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert an expression to `InputForm` without evaluating the expression by using the following construction:

```
expression /. HoldForm[x__] :> HoldForm[InputForm[x]]
```

Unfortunately, I can't illustrate this here with your `1+1/2` example, because there is no way (that I can see) to input 2-dimensional expressions!

Comment: Thanks. By the way, for two-dimensional expressions in stackexchange you generally have to post a bitmap, though in this particular case you can also use Unicode (1+½).

Comment: It's not exactly readable, but you can represent the boxes like so: `\(1 + \(1 \/ 2\)\)`. Or to get the expression: `\!\(1 + \(1 \/ 2\)\)`.